# Is one transcription of "Andrew" more standard than another?

Tags: loanwords, katakana, orthography, names

I recently looked at the [disambiguation page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC) for Andrew on the Japanese Wikipedia, and found that there were several "アンドルー"s, and several "アンドリュー"s.

I couldn't discern any trend that one form tended to be from an earlier time period and the latter was from a later time period, or that one form was from certain languages and the other was from other languages.

Are both forms considered normal transcriptions of "Andrew", or is one form considered more normal than the other?

Comment: Related: [Less-approximate and more-approximate forms of loan words](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4956/542)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the top line on Wikipedia:

> 日本ではしばしば習慣的にアンドリューとも表記されるが、英語での発音は [ˈændruː] であり決して r の後に /j/ を付けて発音されることはない。

"It is frequently habitually written 'andoryuu' in Japan, but as a matter of fact the English has no 'y' sound after the R." So, "andoryuu" is the habit but "andoruu" is supposed to be more accurate. Does it sound right to you?

I notice as well that アンドルー・ロイド・ウェバー has had his name changed to アンドリュー on his Wiki page, so I'm thinking that "andoruu" is sometimes corrected to "andoryuu" by well meaning folks, but someone on Wikipedia is annoyed by this because it doesn't match up to their imaginary perfect representation of IPA in katakana.

Comment: Ugh, this is not your fault, but that sentence from Japanese Wikipedia is pretty inaccurate.  It conflates the phonetic notation with the phonemic notation, phone [r] with phone [ɹ], and palatalization with insertion of [j].