# How is the last name Curry transliterated to japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese

I'm transliterating my friend's names for fun and I'm having trouble figuring out the kana for the last name `Curry`. Would it be `クリ`？ Which doesn't seem right...
It confuses me that this is also an actual Japanese dish. lol.

Actually I'm also unsure about the last name `Castañeda`. I've done about a dozen names correctly by checking Google results and I would like some help with these two. :)

Comment: Are you sure your last name is Curry? Jokes aside, you actually can decide yourself, and カレー is probably not how you want to transliterate the name. I'd think that ケリー, カリー, ケリ, カリ would be viable options.

Comment: In that case my last name is `Curry Castañeda` :D And thanks.

Comment: クリはやめといたほうがいいと思います（笑）

Comment: Related / Possible Duplicate of: [Less-approximate and more-approximate forms of loan words](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4956/542), [Is one transcription of “Andrew” more standard than another?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6401/542).

Comment: I think related but not duplicate.

Comment: @Ash 確かにww どっちかというと「カレー」「カレーライス」ですね

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to translate names, just look for some famous ones in Wikipedia.

[ハスケル・カリー](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC)

Comment: Using the same method, Castañeda would be カスタニェーダ. (Source: [ホルヘ・ウビコ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%AB%E3%83%98%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%93%E3%82%B3))

Comment: You know, it's funny you say that because I looked up famous people with the name `Riddhima` and I just could not find any. I guess I subconsciously stopped looking for famous names because of that.

Comment: In a totally unexpected development, a person famous in computer programming was chosen as the example for an answer. :)