# Are programming languages referred to by their English names or do they have Japanese names?

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct way to talk about coding languages in Japanese? Should the original English name be preserved in the following context?

> トップPythonのコーダー日本2014
>
> Top Python Coder Japan 2014

Comment: [Wikipedia - Python（パイソン）](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) ?

Comment: The string `トップPythonのコーダー日本2014` is the output of google translate for the English string `Top Python Coder Japan 2014`. Please do not trust or use automatic machine translation.

Comment: Python is the name of a programming language, isn't it? It should just be kept in English by any means, otherwise nobody (of the programming community) could understand. Add to it, your example struck me as if the whole words be a title of honor or something. If this is the case, perhaps everything should be kept as is.

Comment: Thank you, @blutorange! I didn't have any other option but the G-Translate at this time. Could this be grammatically wise to say the following: 
 トップパイソンのコーダー日本2014

Comment: I'm afraid neither of them is correct. If I had to translate, I'd put: "日本のトップPythonコーダー2014". But if you're going to use it somewhere public, please read my previous comment.

Comment: @LizaAvramenko Those wards will be used for a name of some event or conference?

Comment: For example, if I write the name `Top Python Coder Japan 2014` in Japanese sentence, I'll write it 'as is'. Japanese people will pronounce it `トップパイソンコーダージャパンにせんじゅうよん` directly from this sentence.
In Chinese, words that Chinese language doesn't have will be written in Kanji correspond to its vocal sound. (e.x. Coca-Cola = 可口可楽 ≒ クコクラ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to katakana-ize the names of programming languages or softwares. Here is an [article about popular programming languages](http://news.mynavi.jp/news/2014/10/03/017/), written in Japanese.

And this may be off-topic, but the word コーダ－ (coder) is often considered lower than プログラマー (programmer) at least in Japanese. コーダー implies a lower-grade, inexperienced person who only writes programming codes as he is told, but is not involved in architecture design. (I think this is the general tendency in Japanese, but it varies from company to company)

So perhaps you may want to translate this "coder" as more generic プログラマ [(or プログラマー)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B6-or-%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC-words-borrowed-from-english-which-end-with-er), if you want it to sound more respectable.

> 日本のトップPythonプログラマ 2014

Comment: Thank you from all my heart! That is very helpful for understanding both as language so linguistic implications of the words (coder vs programmer)