# How to translate Ubuntu (and it's derivatives) to Japanese?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I have thought of these translations:

> Ubuntu - ユブンツー (yubuntsuu)
>
> Kubuntu - クブンツー (kubuntsuu)
>
> Xubuntu - ズブンツー (zubuntsuu)
>
> Lubuntu - ルブンツー (rubuntsuu)

I only want the translations for those 4 main derivatives.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bajiru

Comment: [The translation for Ubuntu is Ubuntu](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19747/5010). Or do you have any specific reason for using katakana even if it looks weird to the Japanese eyes?

Comment: Why not write **Ubuntu** as ウブントゥ? 　Wouldn't that better represent the pronunciation?

Comment: @naruto I first looked at it in Google Translate and it showed me "Ubuntu", then "ウブントゥ". I know that G Translate is automatic translation and that most of the times its incorrect. Based on that, I thought a correct カタカナ translation might be the best. Since Ubuntu begins with "u", and because "u" corresponds with "ユ", I came up with "ユブンツー".

Comment: So, you know GT is not credible, but still you thought katakana is required based on what GT said? Then you can safely forget katakana translations and stick to Latin alphabet. FWIW, people around me pronounce it as ウブンツ.

Comment: @naruto So, do you mean that I have to edit them to ウブンツ - クブンツ - ズブンツ - ルブンツ?

Answer (score 2):

They're called the same in Japanese as in English and all other languages. The articles about each distro on Japanese Wikipedia just uses Latin characters, like in English. You can see in the article for [Ubuntu](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu) that the way they refer to it throughout the article is "Ubuntu".

If you want to write the names in katakana anyway, you can use the ones given in their Wikipedia articles. They are:

- ウブントゥ (Ubuntu),
- クブントゥ (Kubuntu),
- ズブントゥ (Xubuntu) and
- ルブントゥ (Lubuntu).