# Japanese equivalent for the verb "trigger" meaning to cause something to happen?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

The phrase I am trying to translate is for a project with an internet powered device to do it's programmed purpose, i need to translate the phrase

`Trigger Device`

I found one translation in a dictionary for trigger `引き金`but I think perhaps `トリガー` may be a better equivalent for the verb of **Trigger** in English which means that it causes something. My concern is that there is another use for the word "Trigger" which means a part of a gun.

My concern would be with the grammar of the entire phrase, I do not want to have something like device trigger which would describe a component on a device.

Comment: FWIW, according to the dictionary, metaphorical usage of 引き金 is also recognized (https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E9%87%91%E3%83%BB%E5%BC%95%E9%87%91-364765)

Comment: "Trigger device" alone is a bit hard to understand (it is not even clear if trigger is a noun or a verb). Can you give more context or provide the entire sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is something like [this product](https://github.com/ottijp/google-home-trigger), then トリガーデバイス would be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

To translate "trigger", you can use 起動 and トリガ. (I prefer トリガ without a long vowel marker in technical contexts. See: [ブラウザ or ブラウザー? Words borrowed from English which end with -er](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15807/5010)) 引き金 might also work as a metaphorical expression, but it's not common in technical contexts. To translate "device", you can use 装置 or デバイス.

So 起動装置, 起動デバイス, トリガ装置 and トリガデバイス are equally fine, but the first one may look easiest to laypeople, while トリガデバイス may look appealing to geeks.

(I'm assuming your device is something like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/?nc1=h_ls) or [this](http://hackey-wp-origin.cerevo.com/en/).)